# What Content-Security-Policy blocks Anchor tags Click-Jacking

Tags: azure-front-door, web-application-firewall, clickjacking, content-security-policy

When someone pastes into a text box of a CMS

```
<a href="https://attacker-domain.com/clickjacking_test_hehp.html" >
```

(eg [Click Jacking Test](https://attacker-domain.com/clickjacking_test_hehp.html) )
and it gets rendered in a web page so that a users can click on that link that's a problem.

*default-src self;* is fine if it was not for all the different CDN content.
The *navigate-to self;* only works on some browsers if at all.
All the other examples refer to iFrames/Frame examples.
Ideally the CMS code should prevent this if it were a new system, no so with a legacy system.
The only route I can see is *default-src self + all the other urls;*

How do you configure a Azure FrontDoor/WAF CSP policy to prevent hyper links to other sites?